# How to create gpt partition without the 16MB reserved partition?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, gpt

Anyway to use diskpart or another program to create gpt partition without it auto creating the MSR partition?
This is for a 5tb drive so can't just use MBR.
I need a single unformatted raw partition so previously was just doing

```
select disk 1
clean
create partition primary
```

Which worked great for my <2TB drives but can't do the same for these larger drives.
I can delete the MSR after the fact, but would like to not have the unallocated space if possible.

Comment: use a 3rd party partitioner instead of Windows' built-in tools